# Greppable List of HTMl5 Tags

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML5. I've read a few simple tutorials that have told me the basics.

What I would like now ... is a giant list of:

- all the possible HTML5 tags
- what fields each of them have

Is there some webpage that contains all of this in a single list (so I can grep through it?).

I'd prefer a file that I can grep [rather than a webpage with lots of individual links] since the former is easier to integrate with VIM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this one - http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/reference/HTML%20Specification.html#Specification

(just scroll down a bit to HTML tags)